# pyodbc on google colab

Tags: python, sql-server, google-colaboratory, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to my SQL server on google colab by using pyodbc. However, it tells me that I cannot find the driver.

Code to install packages (I replaced IP, port and password with x)

````
``` !sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
!pip install pyodbc
!pip install chart_studio ```

``` import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
                      SERVER = 'xxx.xxx.x.xx, xxxx',
                      DATABASE = 'Database',
                      UID = 'sa',
                      PWD = 'xxxxxx')

cursor = conn.cursor()
```
````

I get this error:

````
```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-3e54dc10e278> in <module>()
      3                       DATABASE = 'Database_PIL',
      4                       UID = 'sa',
----> 5                       PWD = 'mbdxwko2')
      6 
      7 cursor = conn.cursor()

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```
````

Do you have any suggestion how to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but finally figured out that installing the ODBC package direct from microsoft could solve it. Run the following code as a single batch in colab.

```
%%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

Comment: Tried installing the ODBC package as you mentioned but it throws the error. ```CalledProcessError: Command 'b'curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -\ncurl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list\nsudo apt-get update\nsudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17\n'' returned non-zero exit status 100.```

Comment: @Pravin Facing same error as yours. Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
# install msodbcsql17
%%sh
apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

Followed by

```
!pip install pyodbc
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both of you, this worked for me:

> First chunk

```
%%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

> Second chunk

```
!sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
!pip install pyodbc
!pip install chart_studio
```

> Third chunk

```
import pyodbc
```

Comment: Tried your suggetion as well but didn't worked. any suggestions? ```Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")```