# Error connecting SQL to Google Colab using Pyodbc

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pyodbc

I'm attempting to connect SQL to Colab notebook using the exact code that works perfectly when I run it in Spyder, but throws an error in Colab!

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 17.0};"
    "Server=servername;"
    "Database=dbname;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 17.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

In an attempt to resolve it, I've run the following, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519253/pyodbc-on-google-colab) but to no avail. There's precious little on the web about this issue as well.

```
%%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
!sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
!pip install pyodbc
!pip install chart_studio

import pyodbc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was posted, but since I had the same problem and didn't find an answer anywhere, here is what worked for me:

```
!curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
!curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

I did it in trial and error, but I hope it can help other people.